# Run time error using Jeffrey Way's Generator with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, generator

I am using [Jeffrey Way's Generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators/blob/master/readme.md). The generator is installed successfully, however when I run the following commands, I get the error:

```
 php artisan generate:migration create_departments_table department:string

 php artisan generate:migration create_roles_table department_id:integer role:string

 php artisan generate:migration create_transactions_table department_id:integer      main_menu:string menu_text:string address:string

 php artisan generate:migration create_rolestransactions_table role_id:integer transaction_id:integer status:integer

 php artisan generate:migration create_userlogs_table user_id:integer user:string department:string transaction:string dateandtime:timestamp

not working [RuntimeException]

Too many arguments.

generate:migration [--fields[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--templatePath[="..."]] [--   testing[="..."]] migrationName
```

Why would I be getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare this code from the documentation:

```
php artisan generate:migration create_posts_table --fields="title:string, body:text"
```

To the command you try to execute:

```
php artisan generate:migration create_userlogs_table user_id:integer user:string department:string transaction:string dateandtime:timestamp
```

Your command has 6 arguments: the database name and 5 fields

The command from the docs has 1 argument and 1 option: the database name as argument and the `--fields` option listing all fields